# Trouble understanding itertools.groupby() in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Hello and thanks for looking at my question! I have read on the documentations for python and the top rated question for [itertools.groupby( ) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156602/itertools-groupby-in-python). But I'm still confused as to how this function actually works. Can someone walk me through the `for rank, group in groupby (hand , lambda card: card [1])` iteration? Especially the `lambda card: card[1]` part. From my understanding it is just returning card[1] but there is no variable with card. Also, for `rank, group` is it because there are 2 values for each index of hand e.g. the first card is '3S' hence there is 3 and S for its values? Would there need to have a third variable if the say each index of hand were changed to 3 values? E.g. '3SH'? Sorry if this seems like a question that was already answered, I really couldn't understand it even in simple terms...

```
hand = ['3S', '3D', '3H', '4D']

sorted_hand_by_suit = []
for rank, group in groupby (hand , lambda card: card [1]):
    sorted_hand_by_suit.append(list(group))
return sorted_hand_by_suit

print sorted_hand_by_suit # [['3S'],['3D', '4D'], [3H]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could re-write it as

```
what_to_group = hand
def how_to_group(an_item):
   return an_item[1] 

grouped_objects = groupby(what_to_group,how_to_group)
sorted_hand = []
for object in grouped_objects:
    rank = object[0]
    group = list(object[1])
    sorted_hand.append(group)
```

Im not sure if that helps you clarify whats goin on or not ...

that said this is much better done as

```
sorted_hand_by_suite = sorted(hand,key=lambda card:reversed(card))
```

(although it doesnt quite do the same thing...)

Answer (score 0):

Your example needs some correction.  Here I've refactored it:

**Given**

```
hand = ["3S", "3D", "3H", "4D"]

pred = lambda x: x[1]
iterable = sorted(hand, key=pred)
```

**Code**

```
[list(grp) for key, grp in groupby(iterable, key=pred)]
# [['3D', '4D'], ['3H'], ['3S']]
```

---

**Details**

To understand this, first print the results of the keys:

```
[key for key, grp in it.groupby(iterable, key=pred)]
# ['D', 'H', 'S']
```

Notice, these keys correlate with the groups in the former answer.

The keys of the `groupby` object are defined by the `key` parameter, which accepts a function.  The lambda function `pred = lambda x: x[1]` is equivalent to the following regular function:

```
def pred(x):
    return x[1]
```

Therefore, as each card of the hand is iterated, index `1` of each string is assigned as the key of a group.  In other words, if the card `'3D'` is next, `D` becomes the key of a group.  All *consecutive* cards containing `D` at index `1` will be added to the group.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby) on *How do I use Python's `itertools.groupby()`?*.